# How I get all objects in ram for java application

Tags: java, memory-management, ram

My Java application consumer more ram and old objects still in the memory
need tool to get all objects still in memory and how to remove it.
need tool for testing performance too

Comment: You can take a heap dump and use a heap analyser to inspect all the objects to see where they are being retained.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing the Garbage Collector to run with `System.gc()`? If it's not properly clearing out your items it is likely you have a lot of memory leaks going.

I recommend running a profiler on your application to start finding where you have left objects that are no longer used but cannot be released by the Garbage Collector due to lingering references.

Comment: yes i have run Garbage Collector to run with System.gc(). and  running a profiler but i cant find objects that cannot be released by the Garbage Collector ..